# Use PayPal's own "Thank you" page

Tags: paypal

Does PayPal include its own "Thank you for your purchase" page?  I want to show a thank you page after successful payment.

Currently, my return URL is getting opened in a popup, but that is something I would want to avoid.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You should see PayPal's thank you page by default unless you have set the settings to specifically show your own.  In that case, you can just set it back.

Comment: So do you mean, I don't have to mention the return URL ? or is there any additional setting for it?